# how to get the data from 3 tables in mysql search

Tags: php, mysql, search, inner-join

i have 3 tables called company, customers,and comments.first i add company then the customers are added in customers table and finaly the customers add comments in comments table.

Here is the structure of company table:

```
id      company     type        address
1        abc       running      xyz
2        def       old          asd
```

Here is the structure of customers table:

```
cid company  customername  location
1     1       test           delhi
2     2       test1         noida
```

Here is the structure of comments table:

```
id  company     customer     comments
1         1          test       testcomments
2         2          test1       test1comments
```

now i want to search in cutomers table by customers name, company name and location so i have tried this but unable to get the value of comments on search how can i achieve it.

here is my search query for companyname and location:

```
$sql = mysql_query("Select * from customers AS cust INNER JOIN company AS comp ON cust.company = comp.id where cust.name like '%$term%' or cust.location like '%$term%' or comp.company like '%$term%'");
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mysql+left+join

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT * from customers AS cust INNER JOIN company AS comp ON cust.company=comp.id
    INNER JOIN comments AS com ON com.company = comp.id WHERE ....... 

    (where cust.name like '%$term%' or cust.location like '%$term%' or comp.company like '%$term%')
```

Hope this helps. Replace WHERE filter as you want.

Comment: thanks for ur rply but i want a triple join between 3 tables.

Comment: No prob. Btw this query is joining 3 tables. :)

Answer (score 0):

if you mean that you want to retrieve comments made by which customer then this is an answer to that :

```
$sql=mysql_query("select companies.company, customers.customername,
comments.comments from companies,customers,comments
where customers.cid=companies.id and comments.customer=customers.customername");
```

but notice that you must redefine your tables relations and foreign keys should be ids, not names, my answer won't be optimal unless you redefine your tables relations and remove unnecessary fields. you can find alot about database design and normalization rules